# Flask app loads CSS changes only after computer restarts

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

My problem is that the CSS is not loaded correctly when I run the app. The CSS only refreshes when I restart my computer.... this does not make any sense to me. I even tried different connecting ways( Full path, relative path, let flask create the path...)

Here is my code:

```py
import flask


app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def get_latest_packages():
    return [
        {'name': 'flask','version': '1.2.3'},
        {'name': 'sqlalchemy', 'version': '2.2.0'},
        {'name': 'passlib', 'version': '3.0.0'}
    ]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    test_packages = get_latest_packages()
    return flask.render_template('index.html', packages = test_packages)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return flask.render_template('about.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Python Package Index Demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet"
           href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
           crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/site.css"/>
   </head>
        <body>

      <nav>
         <a href="/">Home</a>
         <a href="/about">About</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="main_content">

      <h1>Python Packages Index</h1>
      <h2>Packages</h2>
         {% for p in packages %}
            <div>
                <span class="title">
                    {{ p.name.upper() }}
                </span>
                <span class="version">
                    {{ p.version }}
                </span>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
      </div>



      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try a deep reload: press `F5` maybe together with `Shift` or `Ctrl`. If that does not help open the CSS file in your browser directly and press `F5`. Don't forget to restart flask and make sure all flask processes have been stopped.

Comment: @KlausD. after 3 years, this comment saved my life. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I first started out with web development, are you sure you arent cashing the site in your browser ? The fact that a restart fixes it makes me think you do. In chrome you can open the DevTools and go to Settings to disable caching while they are open. Go to your site, press F12 and then refresh with open DevTools and see if it helps.

[image]

Comment: OMG that has done the trick.... I would have never thought about it. I was looking for hours at my code :D

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Snake_py Happy to help, happens to many people who start out with web development. Would appreciate it if you could accept my answer :)