# How to run code snippets in PyCharm like in Devtools in browsers?

Tags: pycharm, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

In devtools, you can add snippets and run them instantly:

[screenshot with devtools code snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uoVa.png)

#### How to do something like this in PyCharm? *Without creating a project

I try google it and check PyCharm docs. Maybe it's just impossible?

Comment: You can debug [JavaScript in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+debug+javascript). If by devtools you mean changing CSS on the fly [you're supposed to use devtools for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757984). However, your questions lacks specifics about what you're trying to achieve.